# My while loop in JavaScript gets stuck in an infinite loop when the subtractive condition is included

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop, subtraction, multiple-conditions

I'm doing this exercise where you have to calculate the number of limes needed to get the juice.
It needs a switch statement inside which takes out the first element of the "limes" array, (and that works flawlessly). Until i add the condition to count down the wedges: even if in the cases is specified to subtract a determined amount, at every iteration it seems to ignore it and never meeting the needed condition to break the switch statement

here's the code

```
function limesToCut(wedgesNeeded, limes) {
    let limesNeeded = 0
    while(limes.length != 0 || wedgesNeeded > 0 ) {    
        switch (limes[0]) {          
            case 'small':       
                limes.shift() 
                limesNeeded += 1
                wedgesNeeded -= 6
                break;
            case 'medium': 
                limes.shift()
                limesNeeded += 1
                wedgesNeeded -= 8
                break;
            case 'large': 
                limes.shift()
                limesNeeded += 1
                wedgesNeeded -= 10
                break;
            default:
                break  
        } 
    }
    console.log(limesNeeded)
}

//test cases

console.log("case 1")
limesToCut(4, ['medium', 'small'])
console.log("case 2")
limesToCut(80,['small','large','large','medium','small','large','large',])
console.log("case 3")
limesToCut(0, ['small', 'large', 'medium'])
console.log("case 4")
limesToCut(10, [])
```

where did i go wrong? it seems to not be working even when i exclude the other condition from the loop

Comment: `wedgesNeeded - 10` does not do anything. Compare this to the other cases very closely.

Comment: You're missing a single-quote before "small" on the line limesToCut(80,[small'

Comment: I assume the line `limesToCut(80,[small','large','large','medium','small','large','large',])` has the missing `'` in your real code, because that would cause a syntax error, not an infinite loop. [Edit] to clarify.

Comment: I would think you want `while (limes.length > 0 && wedgesNeeded > 0)`  Otherwise you need wedges but there are no limes, or you have limes but you don't need any more wedges.

Comment: @SebastianSimon i corrected and updated in the answer, yet nothing, it keeps getting stuck

Also the typo is when I pasted from the compiler, it is'nt there in the original code, fixed it, thx

Comment: @James Nope, tried and it wont give the needed results

Comment: Michele can you provide the needed results please.

Comment: What happens when you run out of limes?  You reach a state where you have no limes left but you still need 20 more wedges.

Comment: @James 
Case 1 should output 6
Case 2 should output 7
Case 3 and 4 should output 0

Comment: @James also, the focus is on the wedge condition: when i tried to keep only that in the conditions it kept getting stuck

Comment: Case 1 needs 4 wedges, which would be 1 lime of any size.  Case 2 there are not enough limes for 80 wedges.  I don't understand the required output.

Comment: @james it takes the 0 index of the lime array. also the output does'nt really matters much, the switch statement inexplicably getting stuck does

Comment: It's because for some of your test cases, `limes.length != 0 || wedgesNeeded > 0` is always true, so it gets stuck in a loop.  Consider the case where you need 80 wedges but only have 7 limes which could yield 70 wedges tops (if they were all the largest size).  So there are no limes left but wedgesNeeded > 0, so it loops and loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quoting @James in the comments:
It's because for some of your test cases, `limes.length != 0 || wedgesNeeded > 0` is always true, so it gets stuck in a loop. Consider the case where you need 80 wedges but only have 7 limes which could yield 70 wedges tops (if they were all the largest size). So there are no limes left but wedgesNeeded > 0, so it loops and loops.